# Erro duplicando o formulário HTML na Busca dados PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho o seguinte problema quero fazer uma busca no meu banco de dados e exibir os resultados nas linhas da lista, só que está dando um erro louco, ele reexibe a pagina inteira  três vezes, fica assim oh:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ALGUEM Pode me ajudar?
tem ideia do porque isso acontece?
poderia me ajudar com um código mais eficiente para a busca?
Abaixo segue o código completo:

```html
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "test";
$conexao = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha)or die("Erro: " .  mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco,$conexao)or die("Erro: " .  mysql_error());

$query =("SELECT cod_cliente, nome, cpf, endereco, celular FROM clientes");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>


 // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
 if($total > 0) {
  // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
  do {
  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <meta charset="ISO 8859-1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nocsys.css">
    
     <title>Telefonia - Consultar Cliente</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="containermenu"> 
   php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>

<div class="container">
<form id="contact">
   <h3>Pesquisar Cliente</h3>
    <h4>Por Favor informe os dados de forma correta!</h4>
<fieldset>
 <input name="consulta" id="consulta" maxlength="150" placeholder="nome ou cpf" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" action="pesquisarcliente.php" method="get">Consultar</button>
</fieldset>

<div class="containermenu"> 
<ul>
<li>
<a >Cod Cliente</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Nome</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>CPF/CNPJ</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Celular</a>
</li>
<li>
<BR>
<a>Endereço</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
<a><a>?=$linha['cod_cliente']? = nome vindo do banco após a pesquisa</a></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><a>?=$linha['nome']?</a></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><a>?=$linha['cpf']?</a></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><a>?=$linha['celular']?</a></a>
</li>
<BR>
<li>
<a><a>?=$linha['endereco']?</a></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

  // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
  }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
 // fim do if 
 }
?>

// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
<BR>
<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Alterar</button>
</fieldset>

<BR>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Apagar</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**editado novamente**

```
<?php
$host   = 'localhost'; // endereço do servidor de banco de dados.
$dbname = 'test'; //nome de sua base de dados
$user   = 'root'; // seu usuário do banco
$pass   = ''; // sua senha do banco
$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);

$pegaUsuario = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cod_cliente, nome, cpf, endereco, celular FROM clientes');
$pegaUsuario->execute();
$usuario = $pegaUsuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <meta charset="ISO 8859-1"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nocsys.css">

                    <title>Telefonia - Consultar Cliente</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="containermenu">
        <?php include 'menu.php' ?>
</div>

<div class="container">
<form id="contact">
            <h3>Pesquisar Cliente</h3>
                <h4>Por Favor informe os dados de forma correta!</h4>
<fieldset>
    <input name="consulta" id="consulta" maxlength="150" placeholder="nome ou cpf" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" action="pesquisarcliente.php" method="get">Consultar</button>
</fieldset>

<div class="containermenu">
<ul>
<li>
<a >Cod Cliente</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Nome</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>CPF/CNPJ</a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Celular</a>
</li>
<li>
<BR>
<a>Endereço</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
<a><?php echo $usuario[0]->id; ?></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><?php echo $usuario[0]->nome; ?></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><?php echo $usuario[0]->cpf; ?></a>
</li>
<li>
<a><?php echo $usuario[0]->celular; ?></a>
</li>
<BR>
<li>
<a><?php echo $usuario[0]->endereco; ?></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<BR>
<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Alterar</button>
</fieldset>

<BR>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Apagar</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

alterei novamente o código e testei em minha máquina com um banco que tenho aqui. se tiver algo errado com a conexão, verifique os valores que está usando nas variáveis host, dbname, etc.

Comment: tá faltando as tags para poder publicar ele aqui, se não ele não exibe, mas no meu código está tudo certinho

Comment: então, creio que a questão é que você tá criando a página no if. dentro do if deve constar apenas a parte que voce quer que repita. aproveito pra te dizer que use PDO, pois mysql_query está obsoleto. vou criar um outro modelo aqui e altero já já a resposta

Comment: dá uma olhada agora

Comment: ele não está retornando nada... mas para ele responder como PDO tem que fazer um configuração no arquivo do Xampp não tem?

Comment: creio que nao precisa alterar o xamp. uso aqui no wamp de boa. dá algum erro ou apenas não retorna nada? depois da linha `$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);` use `var_dump($pdo);` e veja se retorna algo.

Comment: Retorna isso
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: alterei novamente o código aqui e dessa vez eu testei e está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. caso apresente algum erro, será nas variáveis de conexão ou no select

Comment: o que foi alterado? eu não consegui enxergar... parece igual

Comment: só questão de vírgulas e adicionei php depois de <?

Comment: você testou? me diz o resultado

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjetoNocSysTest\consultarcliente.php on line 61

Comment: é estranho os dois códigos acima terem a mesma conexão e um dos dois não funcionar :/

Comment: Estrutura do meu banco

TABLE clientes(cod_cliente INT(11)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nome VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
cpf VARCHAR(14) UNIQUE NOT NULL, endereco VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, celular VARCHAR(11)NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(75)NOT NULL);
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

Comment: não é problema no banco, pois você conseguiu conectar com o código de minha resposta anterior. verifique se existem dados no banco. e tente criar uma nova página tendo como base o código que funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

crie um arquivo qualquer PHP e escreva apenas o código abaixo:

```
<?php
$host   = 'localhost'; // endereço do servidor de banco de dados.
$dbname = 'nome_do_banco'; //nome de sua base de dados
$user   = 'nome_do_usuairo'; // seu usuário do banco
$pass   = 'senha'; // sua senha do banco
$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);

$pegaUsuario = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cod_cliente, nome, cpf, endereco, celular FROM clientes');
$pegaUsuario->execute();
$usuario = $pegaUsuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo 'Bem vindo ' . $usuario[0]->nome;
?>
```

verifique se os dados `$host, $dbname, $user` e `$pass` estão corretos.

teste e veja se conecta.

caso funcione, basta adaptar ao código acima.

Comment: Agora Retornou
Bem vindo Thyago Breder Marquy Furtado

Comment: use esse código aqui já que deu certo, e aos poucos vá acrescentando suas tags html e testando. caso apresente algum erro em uma parte específica do código, fica mais fácil de achar

Comment: o insert eu ja fiz e tal, mas a busca nao estava funcionando, me ajuda então a fazer o crud sem o PDO, só a busca mesmo, e um Delete, preciso terminar isso logo e to empacado nessa porcaria...

Comment: pra fazer sem o PDO, basta trocar os comandos de conexão pelos que você estava usando anteriormente